Angular - dynamically importing module fails to load
I am trying to create an plugin-based architecture with Angular where I want to load a module dynamically based on my need and access its component.
Inside my service I have the following code.
      const modulePath = widgetType.componentPath;
      const [path, moduleName] = modulePath.split('#');

      const module = await import(`${path}`).then(m => m[moduleName]);  <-- //* fails here *//
      const moduleFactory = await this.compiler.compileModuleAsync(module);
      const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);


      this.widgetModules[type] = (moduleRef.instance as any).constructor.entry;
      component = this.widgetModules[type];

i have tried all possible combination of the path setting to load a module dynamically, but I keep getting the error similar to below:
"Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:4200/src/app/components/widgets/example-widget/example-widget.module"
As you can see in the image below, the module exists in the path specified.

can someone please help overcome this error.
Update 1
Figured out that when the path is hardcoded like below, its able to download :
 const module = await import('../components/widgets/example-widget/example-widget.module').then(m => m.ExampleWidgetModule);
however I am unable to understand how to pass this as a parameter to this function to load my module based on some business rules.
a simple code like this do not even compile:
const module = await import("../components/widgets/"+ path).then(m => m[moduleName]);
with error Could not resolve import("./app/components/widgets/**/*")

Imports cannot be dynamic because the import paths are changed (compressed) during the bundling process, so at run-time they are entirely different from what you see in the editor.
The reason your example with the hardcoded path works is because the bundler can recognize and adjust the import path during compile-time.

Thanks @Sebastian, do you happen to know a way i can change this if i manage to compile a module externally and make it available to import>

I ran into the same problem when trying to dynamically load a component in routing. But this should work for module as well.
The problem is that the variable in your path is converted to a glob. But when generating globs, each variable in the string is converted to a glob * with a maximum of one star per directory depth. This avoids unintentionally adding files from many directories to your import.
You can try something like this with the plugin I linked:


let component = 'test/testComponent'
let [page, comp] = component.split('/');  
const test = import('../../assets/customPage/customPages/${page}/${comp}.component.ts')
.then((c) => c[comp]);



Also try to add a .ts to the end of your path.
Source
